# iPhone app SQLite prepare statement crash

Tags: iphone, ios

One of the app I am building uses SQLite to store data that was downloaded from a server.

The app itself uses multi threading so as the app launches, the app downloads data in the background while it also presents the UI to the user.

The user at this point in time can begin navigating the app, tapping on table rows to drill into detail pages.

Sometimes when I tap on a table row, the app crashes at one of the many sqlite3_prepare_v2() function calls. It happened a lot more frequent when I allow more than 1 max concurrent operation for my NSOperationQueue. However, it has happened a lot less now that I have limited the max concurrent operation count to 1.

When my app launches, I am opening a database connection and I am keeping it open until the app needs to terminate, then I close the connection.

Here is a sample line it crashes at:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(objDatabase, [strGet cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &stmtGet, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    ...
}
```

Error says EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Like 1 out of 20 or 1 out of 30 app runs, it would crash. So that means my SQL statement works 99% of the time.

Anyone ever had this happen before?

Comment: are you calling sqlite using any object??

Comment: Well, I have a single instance of the SQLite database in my App Delegate *ducks for cover*, anytime I want to access my database, I would do something like [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].objLocalDal doSomething];

Comment: So you have a single database connection that's shared between threads (NSOperationQueues)?

Comment: The entire app only uses 1 database connection. The only time the database is closed is when the app calls the appWillTerminate() method in the AppDelegate.m file.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem.   Go carefully over all the calls to sqlite3_prepare_v2 instructions and make sure that the matching sqlite3_finalize is called for each one of them.  In my case, I had a location where sqlite3_finalize was not being called, causing the crash the next time sqlite3_prepare_v2 was called.   It does not always crash, and it's hard to debug like crazy.   I hope this comment might help you.

You might really find helpful to write stub functions for sqlite3_prepare_v2 and sqlite3_finalize which log these actions to NSLog.   That will help verify the matching calls.

Comment: Well, somehow I managed to get the app working and approved by Apple. I used @synchronized keywords, cleaned up a lot of my code and used NSOperationQueue with ASIHttpRequest to download my data rather than using a while loop to execute a dodgy queue of downloads. Code has stopped crashing ever since. Have moved to using Core Data for new projects now, saves a me lot of headaches and time.

Answer (score 0):

enable zombie objects and check is there any prblem due to released object because most of time exec bad access is due to released objects. and by enabling zombie, you will be told that why app crashed. this may be your memory management is not properly that in different threads, sometimes your management method properly invoke some times not.

enable ns zombie objects from

Product>edit schemes> enable zombie and try to crash the app now

Comment: I have enabled NSZombie. The only thing I got back in the console was "(lldb)" and "Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x4)